# JS map with regions

Tags: javascript, google-api

Afternoon,

I have a requirement to have an interactive map where you can hover over a region (Australasia, East & South East Asia, South Asia etc.), have a "tooltip" or "hoverbox" with some info and then click and get redirected to a region page.

I started looking at Google Visualisation GeoChart with the intention of hijacking the click event but you can only select countries not regions.

Any suggestions for a JS library etc?

Many thanks.

Comment: Why not use a simple: [map](http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/map)? (to start with, at least)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using http://jvectormap.owl-hollow.net/ and overriding the `onLabelShow`, `oRegionOver`, `onRegionOut` and `onRegionClick` methods. Quite a simple and elegant plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Well one way is to set the map as background image of a `div` and match its dimension using CSS. Then register a mouse move listener over that `div`. Now whenever the mouse moves check its coordinate and using that figure out which region is under it.

Now it would be interesting to crack the second problem. How to store the dimension of an irregular shape. Well one way could be divide the image into grids, could be one pixel thick or multiple pixels, depending on how much accuracy you need. Then store it in an array like (0 => (1, 5), 1 => (0, 6),..). In this case it says, for row 0 the region starts at column 1 and ends at column 5. On row 1, the region starts at column 0 and ends at 6; and so on.

I hope this make sense.